# Why does my onClick events fail after getting my cameras center point?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

after grabbing the center of the screen using:

```
screenCenter = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2, Camera.main.nearClipPlane));
```

my OnMouseDown() events stop firing. How do I correct this?

I'm in unity 2d. Removing the code, the onClick events work. I can see the object I click still, just fine. It's very strange behavior which is why I'm desperately asking for help here.

edit: https://github.com/chevalierc/unity-chess if you want to look through my project

Comment: Change `screenCenter = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2, Camera.main.nearClipPlane));` **to** `Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2, Camera.main.nearClipPlane));` and see if that problem is still there. You should also tag the language you are using for this.

Comment: Uh, @Programmer , that suggested change isn't different. The parameters you've used are identical, the only thing you did is remove the assignment to a variable (i.e. discarding the result).

Comment: @Draco18s `onClick` seems to be a custom event. I don't know if `screenCenter` value is used to invoke that event or not. OP says that line of code is the problem. By remove `screenCenter`, you are eliminating possible problems.

Comment: @Programmer Maybe. I guess I'd have to see more code.

Comment: @Programmer I'm using C#. Thanks for the suggestions. I need the screenCenter though. That's why I was assigning it to the variable.

Comment: @Draco18s my bad. It was OnMouseDown not onClick() that was failing.